# Addition of Potentials

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, superposition, linear-systems

Say we have a charged shell A (radius $R$) that is present within another charged shell B (radius $2R$).

The charged shell A has a net charge $Q$ and the shell B has a net charge $3Q$.

Taking shell A into consideration, it has a potential of  $\frac{KQ}{R}$ at its surface. Now, in the interior of shell B there is a potential of $\frac{3KQ}{2R}$.

So, since shell A is also within the interior of shell B, does the net potential of shell A become
$\frac{KQ}{R}$+ $\frac{3KQ}{2R}$?

Can we say that the net potential is [own potential + potential due to other factors]?

Comment: Note that you have accepted an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. Your reasoning is correct. You can simply add the
potentials as Maxwell's equations are linear.

Comment: Thanks, I got confused because of two different answers but yours is right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

If the shell $A$ were the only thing in the universe, then the potential on its surface would be $KQ/R$: that is the amount of work necessary in bringing a unit positive charge from infinity to the surface of $A$.

Since $A$ is actually within $B$, the work necessary in bringing a unit charge to the surface of $A$ is going to be different. Specifically, one would first need to bring the charge till the surface of $B$: this amounts to a work of $KQ/2R + 3 KQ/2R = 2KQ/R$ due to both spheres.

Further, one must take the charge from the surface of $B$ to the surface of $A$. Since one is now inside $B$, no additional work needs to be done to overcome $B$'s electric field, so the only obstacle is $A$'s electric field. The extra work needed is then $KQ/R$ in moving a distance $2R - R = R$.

Therefore, in total, the net work that needs to be done is $3KQ/R$, which is the actual potential at the surface of $A$ in the configuration you have described. Note that this is not simply $KQ/R + \mathrm{other \, factors}.$

Comment: Oh..okay, got it thanks!

Comment: No worries, though you could at least upvote my answer :)

Comment: I would but I don't have enough reputation yet... :(

Comment: In the second strp the energy required is overestimated by a factor of 2.